# Why isn't my load cell detected by openscale?

Tags: raspberry-pi, load-cell

I want to measure the pull force on a rope, so I bought myself a [Sparkfun OpenScale](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/openscale-applications-and-hookup-guide) and [this tensile load cell](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/strain-gauge-pressure-sensor-S-load-cell-electronic-scale-sensor-Weighing-Sensor-10KG-20KG-50KG-100KG/1083523348.html). I just received both of them, so I connected them as described and hooked the OpenScale up to my Raspberry Pi.

[image]

I then opened the terminal on the raspi and started the load cell terminal interface using `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600`:

```
Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.0
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 495
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1477,-32780.74,kg,21.75,0,
```

As you can see though, it says `no remote sensor found`.

I took out my multimeter and measured the voltage on the black and white connectors. When I connect the openscale to the Raspberry Pi it measures 5 volts for about 2 seconds and then it goes down to zero volts. This is in line with the docs on OpenScale which say that the voltage on the load cell is switched off if no load cell is found.

From this point on I'm kinda lost. Does this mean that the load cell is broken? Or does it mean I'm doing something wrong? Does anybody know what steps I could take to find out what's wrong?

Comment: My first thought after looking at the listing for the load-cell was that the wire colors don't match what the OpenScale instructions assume - but then looking at your photos I'm not sure the load-cell wire colors are what is listed on that page (particularly since it says that Output + is yellow, but your photo shows yellow looking like a fatter shield wire). What resistance readings do you measure across the power and output wire pairs of your load-cell (when disconnected ofc)?

Comment: @brhans - I measured the resistance and the results are as follows: any combination of red, black, green and white is around 300Ω. Yellow with any of the others is always 1Ω (I guess meaning not measurable). As you'll understand by now I am a beginner, but I'm eager to learn. Does any of these resistance measurements tell you anything?

Comment: Those measurements are odd. I would expect red-black to be about 700Ω and white-green to be about 650Ω. Yellow to any other wire should be an open-circuit (your multimeter might show that as a 1 on the far-left of the display).

Comment: ... and red-white, red-green, black-white, black-green to all be in the 480Ω to 540Ω range.

Comment: user184926 has correctly **answered** the titular question of detection failure in a post which has been improperly converted to a comment.  Had it remained an answer this question could be resolved, now it can't.

Answer (score 1):

The "No remote sensor found" is about a remote temperature sensor, you can just ignore it.